# Pointer to method

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Anyone knows how to compile this example code under msvc2010 ? (supposedly compiles under GCC)

```
class cmdLine;

struct cmdList 
{
   const char *c;
   const char *s;
   const char *h;
   void (cmdLine::*cmdFuncPtr)();
};

class cmdLine
{
   public:
     cmdLine();
     static cmdList myCmdList[];
     void test();
};

cmdLine::cmdLine()
{
}

void cmdLine::test()
{
}

cmdList cmdLine::myCmdList[] =
{
   {"xxx", "yyy", "zzzzz", &cmdLine::test},
   {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", 0}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   cmdLine c;
   (c.myCmdList[0].*cmdFuncPtr) (); //error (why?)
}
```

I get error C2065: 'cmdFuncPtr' : undeclared identifier and dont know whats wrong ?

Comment: You're missing the declaration of cmdLine::*cmdFuncPtr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this syntax

```
  (c.*c.myCmdList[0].cmdFuncPtr) ();
```

As `cmdFuncPtr` is a pointer to a method of `cmdLine`, it needs an instance of the class to be invoked on, which is `c`. At the same time, `cmdFuncPtr` is a member of `cmdList`, so it needs an instance of the class where it is stored, which is `c.myCmdList[0]`. That's why `c` shall be used twice in the expression.

The expression presented by OP parses as: "Invoke a method on an instance of a class in `c.myCmdList[0]` through a method pointer stored in a standalone variable `cmdFuncPtr`". Such variable doesn't exist, that's what the compiler complains about.